# "/dev/fd/63 No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, bash, 18.04, virtualbox, wget

I've been trying to run a command in chroot (pretty new to this), and I get the following output.

```
root@hostname:~ # bash <(wget -q0 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ubports/unity8-desktop-install-tools/master/install.sh) 
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory root
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TL;DR: copy the `/root` folder outside chroot into the chroot directory

The `<(...)` operator is known as process substitution and is a way to run command, output of which goes into anonymous pipe. That's what /dev/fd/63 is. The idea is to allow external command ( here it's `bash` ) to treat  another commands output as if it was a file. Generally the form would be to use  `<` to redirect that pseudo-file object into `bash`'s input stream.

```
bash < <(wget -q0 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ubports/unity8-desktop-install-tools/master/install.sh)
```

This is generally no different from `wget https://stuff.com/blah | bash`. In both cases, it's generally not recommended to use such commands unless you're hundred percent sure the script you're downloading isn't from sketchy source and isn't malware.

However, since you've mentioned running command in `chroot` and the script outputs `No such file or directory root`, and because bash allows running scripts as `bash script.sh` here your script is being executed, but there's no directory named `root` in your chroot. You could just fix it via `sudo cp -R /root  chrootdir`. For better results I'd suggest just reading the script first, see what it needs, and copy that to the chroot folder, and only then run the script locally within the folder. No need to run wget multiple times

So the script works. Errors in shell scripting generally in form  `<shell>: <command user typed>: error message` so the script being temporarily stored as /dev/fd/63 and runs, it just doesn't find what it needs.

See also,

- [What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/678919#678919)
- [Why does the error message for two colons as a command (::) in bash have three colons, but a single colon give no output?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986395/295286)

Comment: Seems to have worked.
Thanks.
Also, the script is legitimate, and is just to try some stuff in a VM, anyhow, so no security risk.

Answer (score 9):

#### Error message

```
/dev/fd/63 No such file or directory
```

#### Problem source

Indeed the directory `/dev/fd/` did not exist on that machine.

#### Solution

The solution was to create a symbolic link from `/proc/self/fd` to `/dev/fd` like so:

```
ln -s /proc/self/fd /dev/fd
```

Process substitution `<(..)` wouldn't work on QNAP without this.

Comment: Alternatively, you can mount the `/proc` and `/dev` directories of your surrounding file system into your chroot: `mount --bind /proc /mnt/your_chroot/proc/; mount --bind /dev /mnt/your_chroot/dev`

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced the same problem, but then I realized that it only happens if you run with **sudo/root** user.

If I run:

```
sudo bash <(echo "It worked")
```

I get:

```
bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

But if I run:

```
bash <(echo "It worked")
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this exact thing happen to me. Turns out;

SSH through VSCode Terminal (or PowerShell/PSCore) don't like doing this. When I SSH'd through PUTTY everything went well.

The more you know, I guess~